# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataView.DataView(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net

I am using the sorting function for the gridview and getting the above error

My sorting function is

```
protected void gvUserMaster_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    UserMasterClass cs = new UserMasterClass();

    ResultClass objres = cs.fn_GetUserMasterList();
    if (objres.bStatus)
    {
        eslist<UserMasterClass> OBJLIST = objres.objData as eslist<UserMasterClass>;
        if (OBJLIST.Count > 0)
        {

            DataTableConverter<UserMasterClass> dt = new DataTableConverter<UserMasterClass>();
           dt.GetDataTable(OBJLIST);

            if (dt != null)
            {

                DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

                gvUserMaster.DataSource = dataView;
                gvUserMaster.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on this line DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're trying to pass a `DataTableConverter<UserMasterClass>` into a constructor which expects a `DataTable`. You're also calling `GetDataTable` and ignoring the result, just beforehand. Perhaps you meant:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dt.GetDataTable(OBJLIST));
```

(As an aside, your naming conventions are all over the place - I'd strongly advise you to follow the [normal .NET conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).)

Comment: Thanks it is working, but can u help me with sorting. The problem is that the sort happens only in one direction ie. ascending how to make it in both the asc and desc.

Comment: @asifa: That sounds like a completely different problem - and we don't know what `ConvertSortDirectionToSql` returns.

Comment: @asifa: So what happens if `e.SortDirection` is descending? It certainly looks like it should be okay...

Comment: It remains Descending the data is always sorted in the descending direction it never changes to ascending.

Comment: @asifa: So when you say "the sort happens only in one direction ie. ascending" you actually meant "the sort happens only in one direction ie. descending"? It helps to be accurate on this...

Comment: @asifa: I've just had another look at your pastebin - your switch statement appears to have the cases the wrong way round...

Comment: @asifa: Well to start with, switch them round to that Ascending maps to ASC, and Descending maps to DESC. But after that, you should debug through the code to work out exactly what's going on. For example, have you looked through to see whether the sort expression is correct after the call?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i sorted out the problem by using ViewState and totally eliminating that function. Thanks